# If $\int^1_0f(x) {\operatorname d}x=\int^1_0xf(x){\operatorname d}x=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\int_0^1 ((f(x))^2+(x^2-x)h'(x)){\operatorname d}x =?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]\to R$ be defined as  $f(x)=h(x)+9x-4$, where $h(x)$ is some integrable function. If $\int^1_0f(x) {\operatorname d}x=\int^1_0xf(x){\operatorname d}x=\frac{1}{2}$, then the possible value(s) of $\int_0^1 ((f(x))^2+(x^2-x)h'(x)){\operatorname d}x $ can be :

My attempt:

Let $y=f(x)$

$y’=h’(x)+9$

Integration ${y^2+(x^2-x)(y’-9)}dx$

Integration ${y^2+2xyy’-2xyy’+(x^2-x)y’}dx +3/2$

Integration ${-2xyy’+(x^2-x)y’dx} +y^2(1)+3/2$

Some hint please.

Comment: I got rid of the image and used Mathjax instead, you should use Mathjax as well, verify the edit is correct and fix up the rest yourself.

Comment: Did you figure out the answer?